# How would I move the text lower on here?

Tags: html, text

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/xgckxtes/1/

How would I move the text lower using only html?

```
<div style="display: block;background-color:black; color:white; width: 266px; height:266px;x;  border-radius:50px">

<p><q>Never let society to turn you into a grain of sand on the beach. Be different, be individual. Refuse to look alike with others. Leave your herd, only then you will have a real name and till then your name will remain as the grain of sand.</q> - <em>Mehmet Murat ildan</em></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="display: table;background-color:black; color:white; width: 266px; height:266px;x;  border-radius:50px">

<p style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"><q>Never let society to turn you into a grain of sand on the beach. Be different, be individual. Refuse to look alike with others. Leave your herd, only then you will have a real name and till then your name will remain as the grain of sand.</q> - <em>Mehmet Murat ildan</em></p>
```

Comment: If need to align text at the bottom change "vertical-align: middle; to vertical-align: bottom; "

Comment: Is there a way to put how high or how low you want the text to be?

Comment: <style>
 .item { width:300px; /*width:100%;*/ background-color:black; color:#FFF; border-radius:50px; padding:20px; }
 .item p { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; padding:0; } 
</style>

<div class="item">
<p><q>Never let society to turn you into a grain of sand on the beach. Be different, be individual. Refuse to look alike with others. Leave your herd, only then you will have a real name and till then your name will remain as the grain of sand.</q> - <em>Mehmet Murat ildan</em></p>
</div>

Comment: I can add padding-top: 20px or padding-bottom:20px to the text and that works too.

Comment: while using this code height is not needed. you can also do like this. I have mention before is the easiest way.

Comment: Which set up is the correct way of doing it, or more preferred. Code 1, or Code 2?  https://jsfiddle.net/n6obfr9v/

Comment: Both code one and two works. But code one is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Modify style to display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;

Add padding property. It will make it more beautiful.

padding-top  to adjust top

eg:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background-color:black;
 padding:20px;


color:white; width: 266px; height:266px;x;  border-radius:50px">

<p><q>Never let society to turn you into a grain of sand on the beach. Be different, be individual. Refuse to look alike with others. Leave your herd, only then you will have a real name and till then your name will remain as the grain of sand.</q> - <em>Mehmet Murat ildan</em></p>

</div>
```

modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/djsreeraj/84k62frb/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .item { width:300px; /*width:100%;*/ background-color:black; color:#FFF; border-radius:50px; padding:20px; }
    .item p { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; padding:0; } 
</style>

<div class="item">
<p><q>Never let society to turn you into a grain of sand on the beach. Be different, be individual. Refuse to look alike with others. Leave your herd, only then you will have a real name and till then your name will remain as the grain of sand.</q> - <em>Mehmet Murat ildan</em></p>
</div>
```